# DockerforWindows : JenkinsInstallation : java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 512 but was expecting 256

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, docker-for-windows

I have installed docker for windows and am using windows10 64 bit

I have used the below docker command initially to install jenkins in docker

```
docker run jenkins:2.60.3
```

The above command successfully ran

And now i am trying to port using the below command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins:2.60.3
```

And am getting the below error message

> java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 512 but was expecting 256

I have installed latest jdk kit and checked if the issue gets fixed. But also the same error persists.

```
SEVERE: ERROR: Signature verification failed in update site &#039;default&#039; <a href='#' class='showDetails'>(show details)</a><pre style='display:none'>java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 512 but was expecting 256<br>   at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:189)<br>        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1222)<br>       at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:655)<br>      at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:444)<br>      at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)<br>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147)<br> at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)<br>Caused: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed<br>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)<br>        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:233)<br>    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:141)<br>    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:80)<br>       at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)<br>        at org.jvnet.hudson.crypto.CertificateUtil.validatePath(CertificateUtil.java:93)<br>    at jenkins.util.JSONSignatureValidator.verifySignature(JSONSignatureValidator.java:78)<br>      at hudson.model.UpdateSite.verifySignature(UpdateSite.java:254)<br>     at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateData(UpdateSite.java:219)<br>  at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:190)<br>   at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.updateDefaultSite(UpdateCenter.java:2194)<br>      at jenkins.install.SetupWizard.init(SetupWizard.java:174)<br>   at jenkins.install.InstallState$3.initializeState(InstallState.java:105)<br>    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setInstallState(Jenkins.java:1062)<br> at jenkins.install.InstallUtil.proceedToNextStateFrom(InstallUtil.java:96)<br>  at jenkins.model.Jenkins.&lt;init&gt;(Jenkins.java:952)<br>    at hudson.model.Hudson.&lt;init&gt;(Hudson.java:86)<br>  at hudson.model.Hudson.&lt;init&gt;(Hudson.java:82)<br> at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:235)<br></pre>
Jun 18, 2021 6:51:41 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
Jun 18, 2021 6:51:42 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
SEVERE: ERROR: Signature verification failed in update site &#039;default&#039; <a href='#' class='showDetails'>(show details)</a><pre style='display:none'>java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 512 but was expecting 256<br>   at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:189)<br>        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1222)<br>       at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:655)<br>      at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:444)<br>      at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)<br>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147)<br> at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)<br>Caused: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed<br>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)<br>        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:233)<br>    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:141)<br>    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:80)<br>       at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)<br>        at org.jvnet.hudson.crypto.CertificateUtil.validatePath(CertificateUtil.java:93)<br>    at jenkins.util.JSONSignatureValidator.verifySignature(JSONSignatureValidator.java:78)<br>      at hudson.model.UpdateSite.verifySignature(UpdateSite.java:254)<br>     at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateData(UpdateSite.java:219)<br>  at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:190)<br>   at hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1632)<br>       at jenkins.model.DownloadSettings$DailyCheck.execute(DownloadSettings.java:131)<br>     at hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1.run(AsyncPeriodicWork.java:101)<br> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)<br></pre>
Jun 18, 2021 6:51:42 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 21,665 ms
```

Comment: just haveing the same issue with an older jenkins.... i think its about java.security config

Answer (score 5):

Base on the Deprecation Notice at https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins the "jenkins" image has been deprecated for over 2 years in favor of the "[jenkins/jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins)" image.

The below works fine on my Windows10 Pro:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```