# java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed

Tags: java, jenkins, ssl-certificate, virtual-machine, jenkins-plugins

```
I am trying configure jenkins job for automation purpose. So I installed jenkins setup and it is success and then I am trying to run jenkins.war file in VM but when I run command **java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8889**, I am getting below error
```

Tried few related solution from stackoverflow but nothing worked for this issue.
Seems like java certificate missing but when I run java -version I am getting output for java 8.
What can be possible solutions?

error:

```
[31mJun 09, 2022 2:53:38 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
SEVERE: ERROR: Signature verification failed in update site &#039;default&#039; <a href='#' class='showDetails'>(show details)</a><pre style='display:none'>java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:233)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:80)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.crypto.CertificateUtil.validatePath(CertificateUtil.java:93)
        at jenkins.util.JSONSignatureValidator.verifySignature(JSONSignatureValidator.java:76)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite.verifySignature(UpdateSite.java:219)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateData(UpdateSite.java:198)
        at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:170)
        at hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:890)
        at jenkins.model.DownloadSettings$DailyCheck.execute(DownloadSettings.java:118)
        at hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1.run(AsyncPeriodicWork.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 512 but was expecting 256
        at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:211)
        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1394)
        at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:771)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:452)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
        ... 13 more
</pre>
[0mJun 09, 2022 2:53:38 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
```

Comment: Looks like this deprecation issue mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030962/dockerforwindows-jenkinsinstallation-java-security-signatureexception-signa

Have you checked out running it on lts-11?

Comment: Thank you. Issue is solved now. Issue was jenkins.war was old war which was not compatible with latest java version. Replaced with latest jenkins.war and ran again.

Comment: Also, we need to replace java path and port no in jenkins.exe else another error will come